# How do you get the SwingWorker that code is currently running in?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker

How do you get the `SwingWorker` that code is currently running in? You can use `Thread.currentThread()` to get the `Thread` instance, but I need the `SwingWorker` instance.

Code from the comments

```
private static void loadFeaturesForSym(final SeqSymmetry optimized_sym, 
                                       final GenericFeature feature) 
  throws OutOfMemoryError { 
  final CThreadWorker<Boolean, Object> worker = 
     new CThreadWorker<Boolean, Object>("Loading feature " + feature.featureName) { 
         @Override 
         protected Boolean runInBackground() { 
           try { 
             return loadFeaturesForSym(feature, optimized_sym); 
           } catch (Exception ex) { 
             ex.printStackTrace(); 
           } 
           return false; 
         } 
       }; 
       ThreadHandler.getThreadHandler().execute(feature, worker); 
     } 
   }
```

Comment: `Thread.currentThread().getName()` should return something like `SwingWorker-pool-2-thread-2` ?

Comment: What are you trying to *achieve?*  (As opposed to 'What are you trying to do?', which you've already explained.)

Comment: trying to achieve - the SwingWorker is executing a long running process, and I want to estimate the the% of the work that is done, and apply this to the SwingWorker progress()/publish()

Comment: Since the code is running inside `SwingWorker`, `this` holds the current instance of `SwingWorker`.

Comment: "Since the code is running inside SwingWorker, this holds the current instance of SwingWorker" - how do I get the SwingWorker instance from "this"?

Comment: `SwingWorker x = this;`?

Comment: the code is not directly in the SwingWorker, it calls a method that calls a method, ... long stack trace.

Comment: @user591568 You need to show us your code :)

Comment: private static void loadFeaturesForSym(final SeqSymmetry optimized_sym, final GenericFeature feature) throws OutOfMemoryError {
final CThreadWorker<Boolean, Object> worker = new CThreadWorker<Boolean, Object>("Loading feature " + feature.featureName) {
@Override
protected Boolean runInBackground() {
try {
return loadFeaturesForSym(feature, optimized_sym);
} catch (Exception ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
}
return false;
}
};
ThreadHandler.getThreadHandler().execute(feature, worker);
}
}

Comment: I added the code from the comments to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you create a model object to which the SwingWorker can listen and send those updates out the publish and process methods.  Your other objects should not know about SwingWorker, they should just know about their own progress and publish that out to whoever wants to listen.  It's called decoupling.  Here's one idea for doing it, which uses something that approaches MVC.  I have not compiled this code, but it helps explain what I am talking about.

```
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;

public class ProcessStatus {
    public static final String PROGRESS = "Progress";

    private PropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport;

    private int progress = 0;

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertyChangeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    protected void firePropertyChange(String propertyName, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
        propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(propertyName, oldValue, newValue);
    }

    public void setProgress(int progress) {
        int oldProgress = progress;
        this.progress = progress;
        firePropertyChange(PROGRESS, oldProgress, progress);
    }

    public int getProgress() {
        return progress;
    }
}

public class SomeWorker extends SwingWorker implements PropertyChangeListener {
    public void doInBackground() {
        ProcessStatus status = new ProcessStatus();
        status.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
        ProcessorThingy processor = new ProcessorThingy(status);
        processor.doStuff();
    }

    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getPropertyName().equals(ProcessStatus.PROGRESS)) {
            publish((Integer) evt.getNewValue());
        }
    }
}

public class ProcessorThingy {
    private ProcessStatus status;

    public ProcessorThingy(ProcessStatus status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public void doStuff() {
        //stuff part 1
        status.setProgress(10);
        //stuff part 2
        status.setProgress(50);
        //stuff part 3
        status.setProgress(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: What I am doing now is using a globally accessible Map to link the Thread to the SwingWorker, so any code that needs the SwingWorker can use SwingWorker sw = globallyAccessibleMap.get(Thread.currentThread());

Comment: My gut instinct says that's a bad idea, but I can't see all your code, so I could be wrong.